# How to implement the animation of the circle expanding in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

![enter image description here][1]

This is my first post.
I would like to implement an animation of a circle spreading out like in the image link, how should I implement it?

First of all, we wanted to make the entire screen blue, so we changed the code as follows

```
LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constrains) {
              return Stack(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      ]
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    right: -constrains.maxWidth * 0.1,
                    bottom: constrains.maxHeight * 0.2,
                    child: ClipOval(
                      child: AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                        color: isSwipeEnd
                            ? theme.appColors.primary
                            : Colors.transparent,
                        width: isSwipeEnd ? constrains.maxWidth * 2 : 200,
                        height: isSwipeEnd ? constrains.maxHeight * 1.5 : 200,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
```

However, this doesn't cover the entire screen in blue. Also, why does the center of the circle move from the bottom right to the top left? Why is this? Also, how do I stop the center of the circle from moving?

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Comment: I've edited the post, please check it out.